# Mocking of System API using fff.h in gtest

Tags: c++, c, mocking, googletest

I am facing issue mocking calloc function using fff.h in gtest. Can any one please guide me how to fix this issue
My Code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "stub_sys.h"
#include "sav_v2x_secif.h"
#include "fff.h"

extern "C" {
    DEFINE_FFF_GLOBALS;
    //FAKE_VALUE_FUNC(void *, calloc, size_t, size_t);
    FAKE_VALUE_FUNC(void *, malloc, size_t);

}
```

I am getting the following error output.

```
X86/staging_dir/include/fff.h:1679:68: error: declaration of ‘void* malloc(size_t)’ has a different exception specifier
     RETURN_TYPE FFF_GCC_FUNCTION_ATTRIBUTES FUNCNAME(ARG0_TYPE arg0){ \
                                                                    ^
X86/staging_dir/include/fff.h:6524:19: note: in definition of macro ‘EXPAND’
 #define EXPAND(x) x
                   ^
X86/staging_dir/include/fff.h:6548:32: note: in expansion of macro ‘EXPAND’
 #define FUNC_VALUE_(N,...)     EXPAND(FUNC_VALUE_N(N,__VA_ARGS__))
                                ^
X86/staging_dir/include/fff.h:6550:33: note: in expansion of macro ‘EXPAND’
 #define FUNC_VALUE_N(N,...)     EXPAND(FAKE_VALUE_FUNC ## N(__VA_ARGS__))
                                 ^
X86/staging_dir/include/fff.h:1714:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘DEFINE_FAKE_VALUE_FUNC1’
     DEFINE_FAKE_VALUE_FUNC1(RETURN_TYPE, FUNCNAME, ARG0_TYPE) \
     ^
X86/staging_dir/include/fff.h:6550:40: note: in expansion of macro ‘FAKE_VALUE_FUNC1’
 #define FUNC_VALUE_N(N,...)     EXPAND(FAKE_VALUE_FUNC ## N(__VA_ARGS__))
                                        ^
X86/staging_dir/include/fff.h:6548:39: note: in expansion of macro ‘FUNC_VALUE_N’
 #define FUNC_VALUE_(N,...)     EXPAND(FUNC_VALUE_N(N,__VA_ARGS__))
                                       ^
X86/staging_dir/include/fff.h:6546:41: note: in expansion of macro ‘FUNC_VALUE_’
 #define FAKE_VALUE_FUNC(...)     EXPAND(FUNC_VALUE_(PP_NARG_MINUS2(__VA_ARGS__), __VA_ARGS__))
                                         ^
X86/tmp/tmp/test/test_tmp.cpp:10:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘FAKE_VALUE_FUNC’
     FAKE_VALUE_FUNC(void *, malloc, size_t);
     ^
X86/tmp/tmp/test/test_tmp.cpp:10:29: error: from previous declaration ‘void* malloc(size_t) throw ()’
     FAKE_VALUE_FUNC(void *, malloc, size_t);
```

Comment: It tells you that exception specifier is different: `void* malloc(size_t)` vs `void* malloc(size_t) throw ()`; Looks like some issue mixing C++ with C, I am not sure what exactly though.

Comment: Also cannot reproduce on my PC. With G++ 7.4 it compiles and `nm -D` shows the symbol `malloc_fake`.

Comment: This happens if I also include gtest/gtest.h. This arises due to conflicting definitions in C++ and C. I am trying to test my c based code in gtest framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently wrote a test to check that `memcpy` was being called under certain conditions, so I'll add my 2c:

1. I don't think you can really mock system calls because you'll probably break the underlying C/C++ machinery. If you mock `malloc`, how will the C++ standard library allocate memory?
2. Because of #1 above, you have to jump through extra hoops to have something you can check has been called, etc, *without* breaking other stuff.

To test against system calls, I use [linker wrapping](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld).

> --wrap=symbol
> Use a wrapper function for symbol. Any undefined reference to symbol will be resolved to "_*wrap* symbol ". Any undefined reference to "_*real* symbol " will be resolved to symbol.

[This](https://drewdevault.com/2016/07/19/Using-Wl-wrap-for-mocking-in-C.html) is a pretty good post about that.

I like FFF very much, but in this particular case, I could not use FFF `.custom_fake=__real_memcpy` as I got a `segfault` right away.

My test that counts the number of times `memcpy` has been called is:

```cpp
// Bit of hackery to intercep calls to memcpy. 
//
// We use the linker to wrap memcpy (memcpy is now __real_memcpy) and then 
// provide the __wrap_memcpy  function so we can count how many times it was
// called.
//
// I've tried using FFF to mock __wrap_memcpy and then do
//
// `__wrap_memcpy_fake.custom_fake = __real_memcpy;`
//
// But I get a sigfault right away, so I had to repliacte a bit of FFF's
// functionality. OTOH I didn't have to add fff.h

extern "C"
{

void* __wrap_memcpy(void* dst, const void* src, size_t n);
extern void *__real_memcpy(void* dst, const void* src, size_t n);

}

size_t __wrap_memcpy_call_count;

void* __wrap_memcpy(void* dst, const void* src, size_t n)
{
    __wrap_memcpy_call_count++;
    return __real_memcpy(dst, src, n);
}

class TestMemcpyFixture:public ::testing::Test {

public:
    void SetUp() override
    {
        __wrap_memcpy_call_count = 0;
    }
};

TEST_F(TestMemcpyFixture, test_memcpy) {

    // Do stuff that potentially uses memcpy

    void *src, *dst;

    // Reset the counter
    __wrap_memcpy_call_count = 0;

    ASSERT_EQ(0, my_code_that_calls_memcpy(src, dst, 42));

    // memcpy must have been called only once
    ASSERT_EQ(1, __wrap_memcpy_call_count);
}
```

When linking *your test*, use the linker option `-Wl,--wrap=memcpy`. Run the test normally.

OK, so now what about `malloc`? I'd add a flag in my picture class that would control whether `malloc` succeeds or not.

Cheers!